# Azure B2C App Registrations In the Tennant have No Home Page URL Option

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In the Azure AD B2C Blade specific to that B2C Tenant is the Applications blade.  When creating an Application from the Applications Blade in the Tenant there is no option to set the homepage url.

This is different than When creating an App Registration in the outer hosting Azure AD app registrations.  When I register an app with Azure AD (in the B2C tenant) I get the option to set the URL home page for the app registration.

**Why does MS grey out and suppress the Homepage URL in the Applications in the Tenant?**  Menu path to the blade is:     Home > Azure AD B2C – Applications > MyApp-Properties .

MS warns you that for all B2C Tenant Applications you can only manipulate the app via the Web Portal GUI and that you should not use graph, PowerShell, or other screens to do the editing.

Anyone know why this B2C App url homepage field is not available to applications in the B2C tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual "Applications" Created within the B2C Blade are not stored within the associated tenant. These app registrations are associated to the B2C Service itself.

As the Home Page URL is not actually used by B2C (it is more used by things likethe App Portal or other services like Application Proxy) there is no need to supply it.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, you just answered and clarified so many things with that explanation.  Specifically it is the App Portal and Application Proxy type uses where I would love to use that feature.